# vite env variables replaced twice with vite command

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vite, radix

I have the index.html with following static script.
Since vite doesnt build static file, I added the env variable.

`<script src="%VITE_BASE_URL%test.js"></script>`

The build command replaces the env variable properly, But for the serve command i.e vite
it seems to prefix twice the base url.
The vite config and base url

```
VITE_BASE_URL = /testurl/

export default defineConfig(({ mode }) => {
  const env = loadEnv(mode, process.cwd());
  return {
   base: env.VITE_BASE_URL,
   server: {
     port: 8080
   }
  }
});
```

So the test.js url turns to

```
localhost:8080/testurl/testurl/test.js
```

Can someone let me know what the reason could be.

Vite version is 4.5.0

Comment: Used transformIndexHtml hook to transform it only when build and not serve
https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/3105